# Limit Behavior of Iterated Curvature-Function

Tags: real-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems

What can happen, if one defines an infinite sequence of functions as follows

- $f_0\in C^\infty: x\in\mathbb{R}\mapsto y\in\mathbb{R}$
- $f_{n+1}: \int_0^x \sqrt{1+(f_n'(t))^2}dt\mapsto\frac{f_n''(x)}{\left(1+(f_n'(x))^2\right)^\frac{3}{2}}$

i.e., put informally, if one repeatedly 'plots' curvature as a function of curve-"length"?

By "what happens?" I mean what kind of limit-functions or function-cycles, resp. "attractors" exist.